# Okhttp 3.4.1 inconsistent with throwing IOException?

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm seeing this really bizarre issue with `okhttp`. I am using `okhttp` to upload files to the server via post streaming. It's the same code as in `okhttp` recipes for post streaming:

```
 while ((count = source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    sink.write(buffer, 0, count);
 }
```

This works fine. The loop is inside `writeTo` method, which is part of the `RequestBody` - all like in the recipe. The body is wrapped into try/catch block and on IOException I fail my upload task and move on. This worked perfectly with okhttp 3.0.1.

I've now updated to okhttp 3.4.1 and I'm getting a really weird and inconsistent behavior. I'm testing with switching on the airplane mode mid upload and expecting to get IOException to fail the upload, but sometimes I'm getting it and sometimes not. I can't really figure out what this behavior is connected with. Just killing the app and repeating the test case will throw the expected exception once every 5 times or so.

Wondering if anyone else has seen similar behaviour and if there are any workaround apart from downgrading back to 3.0.1?

EDIT:

It looks like there are several exceptions that are all extending IOExceptions but not all of them make it out of the `okhttp` land.

These two are never reaching my try/catch block:

```
java.io.IOException: closed 
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.Http2$Writer.data(Http2.java:482)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedConnection.writeData(FramedConnection.java:332)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.emitDataFrame(FramedStream.java:516)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.write(FramedStream.java:489)
  at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
  at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:96)
  at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:96)



javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x9bad4480: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:771)
 at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
 at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
 at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
 at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:41)
 at okhttp3.internal.framed.Http2$Writer.dataFrame(Http2.java:494)
 at okhttp3.internal.framed.Http2$Writer.data(Http2.java:487)
 at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedConnection.writeData(FramedConnection.java:311)
 at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.emitDataFrame(FramedStream.java:515)
 at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.write(FramedStream.java:488)
 at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
 at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:91)
```

However, this one seems to be getting all the way to my try/catch block:

```
okhttp3.internal.framed.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream.checkOutNotClosed(FramedStream.java:574)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream.access$1200(FramedStream.java:34)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.emitDataFrame(FramedStream.java:508)
  at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedStream$FramedDataSink.write(FramedStream.java:488)
  at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
  at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:91)
```

I have a feeling this might be something to do with my `okhttp` client being set to `retryOnConnectionFailure(true)`, but if that is the case, why a total loss of connectivity (airplane mode) is considered a recoverable failure?

EDIT 2:

Did some testing with `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` and all of the above exceptions are now making it to my try/catch block. Also added an interceptor (network) and set `retryOnConnectionFailure(true)`, repeated the test and noticed that `okhttp` goes into an endless loop of sending out requests to my server. Bug or a feature and I'm not using it correctly? Really confused with this behaviour..